# Amber Smalltalk - Creating a single .js file for deployment

Tags: deployment, smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I've seen this topic come up a couple times, but I don't think I've seen any
definitive solution
posted.

I've tried the route of combining all my Foo.deploy.js, Bar.deploy.js into a
single .js file, and then including that in the loadAmber() call. This /seems/
to work reasonably well, but the majority of the download size still comes from
Amber internals.

In my application, the worst offenders in size are:

- 200K - jQuery UI
- 95K  - Kernel-Collections
- 90K  - jQuery
- 87K  - Kernel-Objects
- 50K  - Canvas
- 40K  - MyApp
- 20K  - Kernel-Classes

I can't do *too* much about the size of jQuery UI, but I can do a lot about the
size of the Amber core, and the number of HTTP requests needed to fetch them.
The only problem is I cannot figure out how to tell Amber not to auto-matically
fetch Kernel-Objects.deploy.js, etc.

Has anybody managed to package their entire Amber javascript into a single .js
file successfully?

- R. Tyler Croy

---

Code: http://github.com/rtyler
Chatter: http://twitter.com/agentdero

Comment: Please note that as of December 2014 and Amber version 0.13 the last answer which currently has 0 upvotes is the correct one.

Answer (score 6):

The Amber compiler can do quite a bit of stuff:

http://github.com/NicolasPetton/amber/blob/master/bin/amberc#L18-90

The following command will compile jQuery and the listed packages and generate amber-deploy.js:

```
./bin/amberc -l js/lib/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min,Kernel-Objects.deploy,Kernel-Classes.deploy,Kernel-Methods.deploy,Kernel-Collections.deploy,Kernel-Exceptions.deploy,Canvas.deploy amber-deploy
```

Note the lack of spaces between listed filenames.

Also - you can download the Google Closure compiler http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/files/compiler-latest.zip and put it in your home directory (~/compiler.jar) and then run (notice the *-O* option):

```
./bin/amberc -O -l js/lib/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min,Kernel-Objects.deploy,Kernel-Classes.deploy,Kernel-Methods.deploy,Kernel-Collections.deploy,Kernel-Exceptions.deploy,Canvas.deploy amber-deploy
```

Then in your html you can just put:

```
<script src='amber-deploy.js'></script>
```

Comment: I'm receiving a amber not defined error. Maybe it's needed boot.js too? what about amber.js itself? beside your own code, what else would be necessary to load?

Comment: I assume this answer is no longer valid with the current development version, right?

Comment: This approach no longer works for version 0.12. See Amber mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

Starting in Amber 0.13, you can use the RequireJS optimizer to create one minimized JS file, including your own code, Amber, and all dependencies.

[To load Amber 0.13 alpha](http://forum.world.st/0-13-alpha-version-tp4770298.html):

```
(sudo) npm -g install amber-cli@~0.13.0
```

The key is the build file. All RequireJS setup that used to go directly into index.html goes here. For example, a slightly customized app.build.js:

```
({
    mainConfigFile: "config.js",
    paths: {
        ... skipped items there by default
        'lib/jquery-migrate': 'bower_components/jquery/jquery-migrate'
    },
    "shim": {
        'lib/jquery-migrate': [ 'jquery' ]
    },
    include: [
        'amber/requirejs/require.min',
        'amber/deploy',
        'my-namespace/MyPackage',
        'lib/jquery-migrate'
    ],
    out: "all-in-1.js"
})
```

Now, running `r.js -o app.build.js` will now produce a single minified JS file named all-in-1.js, which is the only file you need to load from index.html

Comment: @Hannes - yes, but according to the readme of https://github.com/herby/amd-config-builder, it seems you can break it into one file per external dependency. HTH

Comment: Amber 0.13 has been released. [Deployment](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Deploying-Amber) now goes with a predefined `` grunt deploy``  command

Answer (score 1):

I believe the incantation is now supposed to be like this -

```
./bin/amberc -m Counter st/Examples.st Onefile
```

... where I'm creating a single file distribution for the "Counter" example without actually instantiating a counter. The output file will be "Onefile.js" which contains the necessary amber kernel classes as well as the Counter example class.

However, when I try to load Onefile.js, I get multiple "Maximum call stack size exceeded" errors in the JS console in Chrome and Safari on MacOSX. While I feel the "one file to deploy" scenario is close to reality, there are still some warts to be healed.

Btw adding the "-O" flag to the above command like will result in the output file being passed  through the google closure compiler whose path is expected to be in "~/compiler.jar". i.e. -

```
./bin/amberc -O -m Counter st/Examples.st Onefile
```

will result in a minimized single JS output file, which is nice.

Comment: suggestion: post this as a new question for Amber version 0.12.4. Additional things have changed since Oct. 2013.

Answer (score 1):

### Amber version 0.13 released

Amber Version 0.13 has been [released](https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/releases).

In this version the command

```
amber init
```

creates creates among a number of other files a Gruntfile.js (http://gruntjs.com/).

With

```
 grunt deploy
```

on the command line
your JavaScript file called  `the.js` is changed to contain everything which is needed for deployment.

This means for deployment you only need

- `index.html`
- `the.js`

to put in the target directory.

`the.js` contains only JavaScript. No Smalltalk sources.

With

```
grunt develop
```

you switch back to development mode. You get a short version of `the.js`

Source: https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Deploying-Amber